# What's the relationship between uniform sampler2D and GL_TEXTURE[NUM] and glGenTexture?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

For example, if I want to generate 3 textures using glGenTexture, and there're 3 uniform sampler2D variable in my glsl file, how to bind these 3 textures to these 3 uniform variables, in some specific order?

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate, but similar in spirit to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27261380/3530129. I wrote an answer there that explains the concept of textures, texture units, sampler variables, and how they are all connected, in some detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are textures (think of them like "ink cartridges" spilling out pixels.

Thee are texture units, think of them like slots into which you can plug the texture cartridges.

There are samplers which are kind of like small hoses that can be connected to the texture units.

---

A texture unit which you want to use with the following commands is selected using `glActiveTexture`. By calling `glBindTexture` a "texture cartridge" is plugged into the unit. By setting the numeric value of a sampler uniform to the number of the texture unit you connect it to that texture unit to take its pixels from.